# Escaping spaces in windows, specifically using ntdsutil

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to escape a space while passing parameters into ntdsutil. The issue is, the parameters must already be inside quotes.

My command:

```
ntdsutil "activate instance ntds" "ifm" "create full C:\temp dir\NTDS" "quit" "quit"
```

Is there a way to escape that space in "temp dir"? I've tried single quotes, double quotes and nothing has worked. I'm writing this for a batch script, and the path which it needs to write to is variable, so I must account for spaces somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tripling up the quotes around the path seems to work:

```
ntdsutil "activate instance ntds" "ifm" "create full """C:\temp dir\NTDS"""" "quit" "quit"
```

As does escaping those quotes with a backslash:

```
ntdsutil "activate instance ntds" "ifm" "create full \"C:\temp dir\NTDS\"" "quit" "quit"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was exactly looking for. Do you know why triple quotes work instead of one set?

Comment: Honestly, no, it's pretty weird to me. But the way NTDSUtil seems to be processing the arguments is kind of weird in general. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a directory name without spaces?!

```
C:\TEMPDIR
C:\TEMP_DIR
```

Or the short file name, shown by "dir /x"

```
C:\TEMPDI~1
```